# How to add a JAR to a Spring Boot layered lib/ dir and loading it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app that I extract in layers using layertools jarmode and run:

```
MyApp 
│
└───BOOT-INF
    |
    └-lib
       |  my-jar-here-that-i-manually-added.jar
│   
└───META-INF
    |   ...
│   
└───org
    |   ...
```

How would I make Spring Boot load my externally/manually added jar from its directory automatically?

The jar that I am manually adding is an UberJar built with `maven-assembly-plugin` and I want it to be picked up and scanned by spring. It has a `spring.factories` file inside.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bit of misunderstanding on how Spring Boot works and how java class loading works.

Spring boot looks at all of your declared dependencies and bundles them up into a single jar along with their own custom class loader; a jar-of-jars. This then becomes part of what's available to be loaded by the JVM, but it's not definitive, and this is crucial to remember.

When the JVM starts, it starts loading classes through the class loader on-demand; in this case it would use springs custom class loader. So, spring boot doesn't "load" jars - it makes them available to the JVM in a convenient fashion - 1 fat jar.

**My answer** There are a few ways you can accomplish what you're trying to do; 1 is experimental as I have never tried it

1. Declare your jar as an actual dependency and let spring/maven/gradle do it's job normally - this is my recommendation. And, even if you don't have a dedicated artifact repository, you can configure both maven and gradle to treat a specific file path as a "repo". So, that's not a limitation.
2. Literally just drop the file in your target (maven) or lib (gradle) directory. I don't know if Spring boot just vacuums up all jars in the dir on the assumption they are correct or only the ones actually declared as dependencies. If I were implementing it, I'd only pull in declared dependencies.
3. Directly add it to the classpath when you run the spring boot jar by adding an extra arg: `--classpath mything.jar`

I recommend option 1, then option 3. It depends on what you're trying to achieve and what you have accessible to you